# Existence of singular solution for linear and Riccati's differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My textbook states that, under the assumption of its coefficients being continuous, first order linear differential equation (the same is said for Riccati's equation) does not have a singular solution.
Can someone help me understand this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in these cases you easily can prove the local Lipschitz condition, providing uniqueness and thus prohibiting singular solutions or any tangency of different solutions.

$y'(x)=a(x)y(x)+b(x)$ has $y$-derivative $a(x)$ and thus the maximum over $a(x)$ over some fixed interval in its domain as global $y$-Lipschitz constant.

$y'(x)=a(x)y(x)^2+b(x)y(x)+c(x)$ has $y$-derivative $2a(x)y+b(x)$  which in any bounded set in the $x$-$y$ plane is bounded and thus gives a local $y$-Lipschitz constant.